# Count the number of records in an excel until Total is displayed

Tags: vba, excel

An excel file is extracted daily, and the number of records vary. Suppose 10 records are displayed, Total is displayed in the last row of A1 column. After that there is one more table below it. I need to count the number of rows from A2 to before total.  Have written the below code:

```
myRange = Range("B65536")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) <> 0 Then
    lastCol = Cells.Find("Total", Range("B1"), xlPart, , xlByRows, xlDown, False).Row
    MsgBox lastCol
Else
    lastCol = 1
End If
```

Comment: Great that you have written the code. Is there a problem? And what is it? And you need to look at column A if that is where Total is.

Comment: Its returning the count as 1.

Comment: @user9351236 - of course it is returning Count as 1 - You are practically counting only `Range("B65536")` and there `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)` it either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Ok. So what range should I mention as it will vary everyday.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the word "Total" on column A, the following code will show a msgbox with the row number:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim TotalRow As Long
TotalRow = ws.Range("A:A").Find("Total").Row
'look for the word "Total" on Column A
MsgBox "Your desired Range is from A2 to A" & TotalRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as small as this one should find the row of the "Total" in the first column:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim rowWithTotal As Long
    rowWithTotal = Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Find("Total").Row
    MsgBox "Row with total is - " & rowWithTotal
End Sub
```